# Is there a jQuery / JS plugin to do a map similar to google maps?

Tags: jquery, plugins, maps

Of course, the map would not be of a city, so I cannot use a Google Maps plugin.  What I need, more or less, is this:

- Use my own image as a map
- The map will have hotspots that must be responsive to hover and clicks.
- To drag the map with the mouse, as in Google Maps.

Does anyone know of a plugin like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, it's called OpenLayers and you can get it up and running with OpenStreetView in less then 10 mins.

http://openlayers.org/